# Unable to use Google Chrome as the external browser in Eclipse

Tags: google-chrome, php, eclipse

I'm trying to use Google Chrome as the external browser for Eclipse PDT. I always get the following error:

> Could not launch external web browser for http://... Check
>   the Web Browser preferences.

I tried using Firefox and IE and they both work. How can I get Chrome to work?

Edit: I am using `Eclipse for PHP Developers` version 3.0.2 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

Comment: Which version of eclipse?

Comment: It's version 3.0.2

Comment: See some solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322574/how-can-i-set-chrome-as-default-external-browser-in-eclipse-for-mac

Comment: Another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304854/is-there-a-way-to-add-google-chrome-as-an-external-web-browser-in-flash-builder

Comment: Both of those are for Mac OS X, I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the "External Tools" to setup browsers and select the one I want to use.

### Step by step guide

1. Access the menu "Run";
2. Select the last option labelled "External Tools";
3. Select the "External Tools Configurations...";
4. Create a "New launch configuration";
5. Enter the following settings:

   #### Name

   ```
    Google Chrome
   ```

   <sup>(or whatever you wish to called it)</sup>

   #### Location

   ```
    C:\Users\Zuul\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
   ```

   <sup>(you can use **Browse File System** to locate it)</sup>

   #### Working Directory

   ```
    ${workspace_loc}
   ```

   #### Arguments

   ```
   -url "${workspace_loc}${project_path}/${resource_name}"
   ```
6. Press **Apply**;
7. You can now run it or later on select it from the menu "Run" -> "External Tools".

[image: External Tools - New launch configuration]

Answer (score 2):

For Eclipse running on Ubuntu (12. 04) - start Chrome and then determine the location of the process.

From the terminal prompt:

```
~$ ps -aux
```

In my system, Google Chrome is running from:**/opt/google/chrome/**

In the External Tools Configuration, browse file system to this path/process.

Mine is:**/opt/google/chrome/chrome**